# good question on summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\frac{(2k+1)\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+1-m)!(k-m-1)!(m+1)!m!}}{4^{2k+1}}$$
pls evaluate this. I tried to evaluate this but failed. Can anybody help me. I tried to find that if the summation was telescoping but failed. I also wrote a code
This gives the upper summation as a convergent series. But how is this even possible. Any body please help me

Comment: What is the question? Evaluate the sum? Why? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+1-m)!(k-m-1)!m!(m+1)!} = \binom{k+1}{m}\binom{k}{m+1}\binom{2k+1}{k}$$
so by Vandermonde's identity
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+1-m)!(k-m-1)!m!(m+1)!}=\frac{4^{2k+1} k\, \Gamma\left(k+3/2\right)^2}{\pi\,\Gamma(k+2)\Gamma(k+3)} $$
and we want to evaluate
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(2k+1) k\, \Gamma\left(k+3/2\right)^2}{\Gamma(k+2)\Gamma(k+3)} $$
but this is not convergent, since $\frac{(2k+1) k\, \Gamma\left(k+3/2\right)^2}{\Gamma(k+2)\Gamma(k+3)}\to 2$ as $k\to +\infty$.